# Is there a way to group an excel table similar to a SharePoint list?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data set in Excel that I would like to automatically group by specific columns while keeping the raw data viewable. When using a pivot table, understandably, I can only view a summary of the information. I'm looking for something similar to what I find in a SharePoint list.

For example:
Group By State and City
Display Store Name, Address, Max Occupancy

- Texas

  - Austin

    - Store A | 123 Main   | 40
    - Store B | 456 2nd St | 50
    - Store C | 789 3rd St | 60
  - Houston

    - Store D | 101 Main   | 10
    - Store E | 201 2nd St | 20
    - Store F | 301 3rd St | 30
  - San Antonio

    - Store G | 111 Main   | 70
    - Store H | 222 2nd St | 80
    - Store I | 333 3rd St | 90

During a meeting I'd like to be able to easily move these around. 
Is this possible to do natively in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, normally pivot tables are for summaries.  However, if you include all the fields as row labels, and simply do not put anything in values, you could accomplish your goal, without any loss in detail (assuming every row is indeed unique in some small way).